# Thread running between fork and exec blocks other thread read

Tags: linux, multithreading

While studying the possibility of improving Recoll performance by using vfork() instead of fork(), I've encountered a fork() issue which I can't explain.

Recoll repeatedly execs external commands to translate files, so that's what the sample program does: it starts threads which repeatedly execute "ls" and read back the output.

The following problem is not a "real" one, in the sense that an actual program would not do what triggers the issue. I just stumbled on it while having a look at what threads were stopped or not between fork()/vfork() and exec().

When I have one of the threads busy-looping between fork() and exec(), the other thread never completes the data reading: the last read(), which should indicate eof, is blocked forever or until the other thread's looping ends (at which point everything resumes normally, which you can see by replacing the infinite loop with one which completes). While read() is blocked, the "ls" command has exited (ps shows <defunct>, a zombie).

There is a random aspect to the issue, but the sample program "succeeds" most of the time. I tested with Linux kernels 3.2.0 (Debian),  3.13.0 (Ubuntu) and 3.19 (Ubuntu). Works on a VM, but you need at least 2 procs, I could not make it work with one processor.

Here follows the sample program, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct thread_arg {
    int tnum;
    int loopcount;
    const char *cmd;
};

void* task(void *rarg)
{
    struct thread_arg *arg = (struct thread_arg *)rarg;
    const char *cmd = arg->cmd;

    for (int i = 0; i < arg->loopcount; i++) {
        pid_t pid;
        int pipefd[2];

        if (pipe(pipefd)) {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(1);
        }
        pid = fork();
        if (pid) {
            cerr << "Thread " << arg->tnum << " parent " << endl;
            if (pid < 0) {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            // Child code. Either exec ls or loop (thread 1)
            if (arg->tnum == 1) {
                cerr << "Thread " << arg->tnum << " looping" <<endl;
                for (;;);
                //for (int cc = 0; cc < 1000 * 1000 * 1000; cc++);
            } else {
                cerr << "Thread " << arg->tnum << " child" <<endl;
            }

            close(pipefd[0]);
            if (pipefd[1] != 1) {
                dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
                close(pipefd[1]);
            }
            cerr << "Thread " << arg->tnum << " child calling exec" <<
                endl;
            execlp(cmd, cmd, NULL);
            perror("execlp");
            _exit(255);
        }

        // Parent closes write side of pipe
        close(pipefd[1]);
        int ntot = 0, nread;
        char buf[1000];
        while ((nread = read(pipefd[0], buf, 1000)) > 0) {
            ntot += nread;
            cerr << "Thread " << arg->tnum << " nread " << nread << endl;
        }
        cerr << "Total " <<  ntot << endl;

        close(pipefd[0]);
        int status;
        cerr << "Thread " << arg->tnum << " waiting for process " << pid
             << endl;
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1) {
            if (status) {
                cerr << "Child exited with status " << status << endl;
            }
        } else {
            perror("waitpid");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    int loopcount = 5;
    const char *cmd =  "ls";

    cerr << "cmd [" << cmd << "]" << " loopcount " << loopcount << endl;

    const int nthreads = 2;
    pthread_t threads[nthreads];

    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        struct thread_arg *arg = new struct thread_arg;
        arg->tnum = i;
        arg->loopcount = loopcount;
        arg->cmd = cmd;
        int err;
        if ((err = pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, task, arg))) {
            cerr << "pthread_create failed, err " << err << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    void *status;
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
        if (status) {
            cerr << "pthread_join: " << status << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I enjoyed solving your puzzle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that your pipes are getting inherited by both child processes instead of just one.

What you want to do is:

1. Create pipe with 2 ends
2. `fork()`, child inherits both ends of the pipe
3. child closes the read end, parent closes the write end

...so that the child ends up with just one end of one pipe, which is `dup2()`'ed to stdout.

But your threads race with each other, so what can happen is this:

1. Thread 1 creates pipe with 2 ends
2. Thread 0 creates pipe with 2 ends
3. Thread 1 `fork()`s. The child process has inherited 4 file descriptors, not 2!
4. Thread 1's child closes the read end of the pipe that thread 1 opened, but it keeps a reference to the read end and write end of thread 0's pipe too.

Later, thread 0 waits forever because it never gets an EOF on the pipe it is reading because the write end of that pipe is still held open by thread 1's child.

You will need to define a critical section that starts before `pipe()`, encloses the `fork()`, and ends after `close()` in the parent, and enter that critical section from only one thread at a time using a mutex.

Comment: Just a trivial remark: the critical section needs to end after the parent close, not after the fork, else the other child can still inherit the fd.

Comment: You're right about the `close()`, I edited my answer.